# Adding images on specific coordinates (OpenCV, matplotlib)

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, image-processing

I have an image with coordinates of specific spots which should be replaced with certain images. The coordinates are represented as 3D numpy array with arbitary shape where 1st dimension is the different classes of the images. Plotting `array[1, :,]`.

How should i approach this?

Comment: One idea is to use color thresholding to identify all teal spots, find contours, for each contour, adjust orientation, resize the template icon to the same dimensions as the contour then use Numpy slicing to copy/paste the icon onto the image

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the below code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage import measure


def resize_image(img,size):
    img = cv2.resize(img,(img.shape[0],size[1]),interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
    img = cv2.resize(img,size,interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
    return img


FINAL_TILE_WIDTH = 8

#loading image
tile_mask = cv2.imread("tile.png")
tile_mask = cv2.cvtColor(tile_mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
tile_mask = resize_image(tile_mask,(36,FINAL_TILE_WIDTH))

img = cv2.imread("image.png")
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img[img < 127] = 0
img[img != 0] = 255

#final image will be stored here
final_image = np.zeros(img.shape).astype(np.uint8)


#perform connected components on the image
img = measure.label(img).astype(np.uint8)

labels = np.unique(img)

#removing noise detections
for i in labels:
    if i != 0:
        if len(np.where(img == i)[0]) < 30:
            img[img == i] = 0

img[img != 0] = 255

#extracting the contours of all the rectangles. They might not completely be rectangles.
#but the following operation will make sure everything works fine.
_,cnts,_ = cv2.findContours(img.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
    cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

#iterate trough each contour detected
for cnt in cnts:
    #extract the extreme points, here the assumption of rectangles oriented along axis is taken.
    (minX ,minY)= np.min(cnt,axis = 0)[0]
    (maxX, maxY) = np.max(cnt,axis = 0)[0]
    width = maxX - minX
    width = width - width%2
    height = maxY - minY
    height = height - height%2
    center = (int((maxX+minX)/2),int((maxY+minY)/2))
    #find if width is higher or height is higher. This will be used to orient the tile vertically or horizontally.
    orientation = (width > height)
    temp_tile_mask = []
    tile_width = 0
    tile_height = 0
    #change the orientation of the tile
    if orientation:
        temp_tile_mask = tile_mask
        tile_width = width
        tile_height = FINAL_TILE_WIDTH
        temp_tile_mask = resize_image(temp_tile_mask,(tile_width, tile_height))
    else:
        temp_tile_mask = np.transpose(tile_mask)
        tile_width = FINAL_TILE_WIDTH
        tile_height = height
        temp_tile_mask = resize_image(temp_tile_mask,(tile_width, tile_height))
    #apply the tile to the final image
    final_image[center[1]-int(tile_height/2):center[1]+int(tile_height/2),
                center[0]-int(tile_width/2):center[0]+int(tile_width/2)] = temp_tile_mask[:,:]


cv2.imshow("img", final_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: The Final Image]

I did not really work on any optimization, just getting to the requirement.
Also in the above image, the tiles look very smoothened, some resizing can be changed to resolve this.